# Why my batch script doesn´t replace correctly?

Tags: arrays, loops, file, text, replace

I have this script to replace some words at text file.
I don't know if is correct:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set count=0
set j=0
set i=0

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%c in ( '"type test.txt"') do (
    SET string=%%b
    echo %%c >>test2.txt
)

for /F %%a in (params.txt) do (
    set array[!i!]=%%a
    set /A i+=1
)
for /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%p in (params.txt) do (
    set array2[!j!]=%%p
    set /A j+=1
)
set /A i-=1
for /l %%r in (%count% , 1, %i%) do (
   set replace=!array2[%%r]!
   echo %repace%
   set replaced=!array[%%r]!
   echo replaced
   set /A count+=1
   call :reemplaza
)


:reemplaza

if %count% LSS %i% ( 
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%b in ( '"type test2.txt"') do (
        SET string=%%b
        SET modified=!string:%replace%=%replaced%!s
        echo.!modified! >>auxiliar.txt
    )
    pause
    del test2.txt
    ren auxiliar.txt test2.txt
)
```

First loop is correct but at second loop do this:

I wanna replace:
name=awachens for name=awachenss

So take next parameter and print:

name=awachens=surname=lol

Regards !

Comment: mmmm... Batch script

Comment: Good morning !! I know where is the problem but dont know what is the solution jeje. Problem is in  SET modified=!string:%replace%=%replaced%! -> Is not getting the values of variables correctly.. Why ? If i do echo.!replace! i have the value.